# javaScript is not recognised at all

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a simple web page so I can use JavaScript. The code below is a very small piece of it. The javascript I have wrote in it will not do anything. I don't know why. I know this isn't something difficult to do but I have no idea what is wrong with it. Its like the script isn't recognized by the browser at all. Could someone please help me with this problem?

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <title>Add User</title>
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo.png"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
            <script type="text/javascript">     
                function changeBackground() 
                {
                    alert("Java is working!");
                    document.getElementByID("top_nav").background-color = "green";
                    document.getElementByID("top_nav").innerHTML = "green";
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="top_nav" onload="changeBackground()" style="height: 500px; width: 500px;">
<button type="button" onclick="changeBackground()">button</button>
</div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: You’ve got syntax errors, semantic errors and misspellings within two lines of code. And the language you’re writing in is called JavaScript, not Java.

Comment: Hit F12 for the developer console. That's where you'll see the errors reported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no div 'onload' event.  You weren't calling the correct function (javascript is case sensitive) for getting the element by ID, it's backgroundColor not background-color, and it's off the style object, not the html element itself.

Also, this is JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <title>Add User</title>
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo.png"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
            <script type="text/javascript">     
                function changeBackground() 
                {
                    alert("JavaScript is working!");
                    document.getElementById("top_nav").style.backgroundColor = "green";
                    document.getElementById("top_nav").innerHTML = "green";
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="top_nav" style="height: 500px; width: 500px;">
<button type="button" onclick="changeBackground()">button</button>
</div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be `document.getElementById("top_nav").style.backgroundColor` and `getElementById`, not `getElementByID`:

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <title>Add User</title>
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo.png"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
            <script type="text/javascript">     
                function changeBackground() 
                {
                    alert("Java is working!");
                    document.getElementById("top_nav").style.backgroundColor = "green";
                    document.getElementById("top_nav").innerHTML = "green";
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="top_nav" onload="changeBackground()" style="height: 500px; width: 500px;">
<button type="button" onclick="changeBackground()">button</button>
</div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: *"Here you go"* followed by code is a poor description of the problem. Describe what you changed, and why it needed to be changed.

Comment: Thanks for feedback!

Comment: Definitely improved. Removed my -1. Thank you.